# Обработка запросов Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

В процессе работы возник вопрос, а как Flask обрабатывает запросы. Точнее может ли быть такая ситуация, что одновременно обрабатываются несколько запросов или они берутся из очереди и выполняются последовательно? Стоит ли при работе с базой данных учитывать случай, когда начинает выполняться два параллельных запроса?

Comment: При работе с базой стоит использовать транзакции — независимо от того, параллельно или нет, фласк или не фласк

Comment: Я планирую обращаться к службе каталогов по LDAP и не совсем уверен, что в пределах одного соединения такое возможно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот тут можно найти более детальное объяснение: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/

Но:
 1. Параллельно, каждый запрос в своем котексте.
 2. Да, если 2 пользователя одновременно запросили данные по адресу.
 3. Только если вы пишете данные и возможно состояние коллизии. Если вы, например, добавляете временную сессию пользователя и индексное поле в БД имеет тип autoincrement или просто проверяяете логин пароль, то не обязательно. Или если несколько пользователей никогда не будут работать с одним набором данных.

Но вообще лучше всегда использовать транзации, в случае update/delete.